# Why are composite methods declared in Component interface?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In the gang of four book, the Composite pattern is defined with the diagram
[image]

Why are methods only related to Composite part of the `Component` interface? If the methods (`Add`, `Remove`, `Getchild`) were part of `Composite` and not the general interface, Composites and Leaves would still both implement the `Component` interface and thus be used interchangably as is one of the purposes of the Composite pattern. By having both `Leaf` and `Composite` implement `Component` (that only requires `Operation` now), the client would still treat them the same like

```
Component anobject = new Leaf();
Component another = new Composite();
another.Operation();
anobject.Operation();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Composite Pattern SOLID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579520/is-the-composite-pattern-solid)

Answer (score 1):

Because you *treat* composites and leafs the same. You program to interface, not to concrete objects.

In your example, you couldn't do:

```
Component l = new Leaf();
Component c = new Composite();

// now you can't do this because Composite doesn't know about add() method, only concrete subclass know in your variation.
composite.add(l);
```

Comment: Yea but wouldn't the client just create objects of `Composite` type and then directly on this object call `add` to add Component types. Then, from there on, you could store both the `Composite` object and `Leaf` or `Component` objects in a List of `Component`s as if `Leaf` and `Component` were the same? Then they would still be treated the same, right?

Answer (score 0):

GOF define this kind of implementation because they want guarantee `transparency` that means client should see both of leaf and composite in the same manner but this approach violate `Lyskov` principal in `SOLID` .

There are another implementation that moves methods to child's side for guarantee `safty`  .

Both of them are acceptable and mentioned in books and each of them as I indicates has cons and pros.