# Does the composite design patterm adhere the principles of SOLID (spacialy the L and the I)?

Tags: design-patterns, composite, interface-segregation-principle, solid

Does the composite design template adhere to the principles of solid?
if all the compositing method are declared at the component its violation of the Interface Segregation Principle. if compositing method are declared at the composite its violation of Liskov Substitution Principle - because we change are behaver when it leaf and when it composite.
am i wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Composite Pattern SOLID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579520/is-the-composite-pattern-solid)

Comment: The GoF book addresses this issue on page 167. I've quoted them in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52952616/1371329) to the above thread.